# Can't get serial port's attention once sketch is running

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

This sketch is supposed to listen for a single character sent to the serial port, as a means of starting and stopping data collection (which in this example is mocked by printing some register values).  It reacts to the first character sent (`g`), and the `while` loop begins executing.  But it doesn't react to a subsequent `s` character, it seems I can't get Arduino's attention.

Perhaps this is related to this [answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/72312/93110) but I'm not sure.  If that's the problem, I could use some general suggestions about how to work around the limitations.  If it's something else, well obviously I need a suggestion for that as well!

```
// Listen to the Serial Port for Instructions and Print Register Values

volatile boolean start = false;  // flag to start register inspection; global

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (Serial) {
    Serial.println("Arduino listening...");
    Serial.println("Enter g or s at any time");  // g = go, s = stop
  }
}

void loop() {
  unsigned char data;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    data = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(data); // only for troubleshooting
    if (data == 'g') {
      start = true;
    }
    else  if (data == 's') {
      start = false;
    }
  }
  
  while (start) {
    // print the values of some ADC registers
    Serial.print("ADMUX  register: ");
    print_bin(ADMUX);
    Serial.print("ADCSRA register: ");
    print_bin(ADCSRA);
    Serial.println(" ");
    delay(1000);
  }
}


void print_bin(byte aByte) {
  for (int8_t aBit = 7; aBit >= 0; aBit--) {
    if (aBit == 3) {
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.print(bitRead(aByte, aBit) ? '1' : '0');
  }
  Serial.println(" ");
}
```

Environment:
Version: 2.3.0
Date: 2024-02-07T13:40:21.377Z
CLI Version: 0.35.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your `while (start) {` loop that would allow `start` to become `false`.

```cpp
  while (start) {
    // print the values of some ADC registers
    Serial.print("ADMUX  register: ");
    print_bin(ADMUX);
    Serial.print("ADCSRA register: ");
    print_bin(ADCSRA);
    Serial.println(" ");
    delay(1000);
  }
```

...and so your loop continues while data is piling up in `Serial`'s input buffer.

`loop()` is already a functional loop. Changing `while (start) {` to `if (start) {` seems to be what you're looking for.

```cpp
void loop() { // <-- existing loop
  unsigned char data;
  if (Serial.available()) {   
    // stuff that can change start
  }
  
  if (start) {
    // stuff that happens if start is true
  }
}
```

You may want to look at the [blink without delay example](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/BlinkWithoutDelay/) for handling your `delay(1000)` differently.

Comment: Dang, I set up a loop inside a loop with no escape from the inner loop once it was going!  Thanks for the second set of eyes!  Just couldn't see that for some reason.

Comment: And thanks for the link to the blink nuances.  I don't actually need that delay in there, but I need to keep learning about Arduino blocking, interrupts etc.  Many details are not readily apparent when one is already learning a lot of new stuff.